# Contract.Invariant not check by static verifier

Tags: .net, code-contracts

I'm experimenting with Code Contract and I encountered one problem. I have class:

```
public class SpecialPoint
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public SpecialPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(y > x);
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }


    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void ClassContract()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(Y > X);
    }
}
```

and I run a test against it:

```
[TestFixture]
class SpecialPointTests
{
    [Test]
    public void SpecialPoint()
    {
        var p = new SpecialPoint(10, 20); 
        p.X = 30;
    }
}
```

I expected static checker to warn me about assignment p.X =30; as this violates invariant but it only takes place during runtime.
I have static analysis enable. My version is 1.7.11202.10.

Answer (score 3):

From the [MSDN page on Contract.Invariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412890(v=vs.110).aspx)

> During **run-time checking**, invariants are checked at the end of each public method.